# how to get ICONs of files and folders to insert to treeView and listView like windows explorer?

Tags: c#, listview, treeview

i use a treeView and a listView to display file and folders like Windows Explorer. Can anyone help me, how to get ICONs of files and folders to insert them before folders name or files name in treeView and listView?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not do your homework. Did you google?

[Excellent Codeproject example for retrieving icons.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/fileicon.aspx)

Comment: :) Kudos to StackOverflow team then!

Answer (score 3):

You could download and use the icons contained in the [Visual Studio Image Library](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825).

> The Visual Studio Image Library contains application images that appear in Microsoft Visual Studio, Microsoft Windows, the Office system and other Microsoft software.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio comes with a wide variety of icons that you can use. They are places in the visual studio installation folder under `common7\VSXXXXImageLibrary`.